# Placing the operator T|u in the Minimal polynomial of T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

If u is an invariant subspace of V as for transformation T why do we get 0 if we place T|u inside the Minimal polynomial of T ? Is that a trivial fact for every subspace? 
Thank you

Comment: The caracteristic polynomial annihilates T, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking but here is a guess.

Let $S= T \mid U$. For every polynomial $p$, we have: if $p(T)=0$, then $p(S)=0$.

In particular, this holds for $p$ the minimal polynomial of $T$.

The hypothesis that $U$ is an invariant subspace is needed here to make sense of powers of $S$.
If you interpret $S : U \to V$ instead of $U \to U$, then $S^2$ does not make sense if $U$ is not invariant.

The more interesting fact, which follows from the argument above, is: if $U$ is an invariant subspace, then the minimal polynomial of $S$ divides the minimal polynomial of $T$.